# ERROR: Function failed: do_compile with open embedded using SabreLIte

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, openembedded

i'm trying to compile a kernel with bitbake using open-embedded. Normally, it works because i've done it several times before but since yesterday, after modifying some values with make menuconfig, and when i type to compile with:

**bitbake linux-boundary -c compile**

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/\
     setup-scripts/build/tmp-defaultsetup-eglibc-eglibc/work/\
     nitrogen6x-oe-linux-gnueabi/linux-boundary/3.0.35-r0/temp/\
     log.do_compile.8182)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/\
     setup-scripts/build/tmp-defaultsetup-eglibc-eglibc/work/\
     nitrogen6x-oe-linux-gnueabi/linux-boundary/3.0.35-r0/temp/\
     log.do_compile.8182
```

And when, i open the log file, it says:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j9 uImage CC=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb-interwork -marm LD=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd   LOADADDR=0x10008000
| scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
| *
| * Restart config...
| *
| *
| * Linux/arm 3.0.35 Kernel Configuration
| *
| Patch physical to virtual translations at runtime (EXPERIMENTAL) (ARM_PATCH_PHYS_VIRT) [N/y/?] (NEW) aborted!
| 
| Console input/output is redirected. Run 'make oldconfig' to update configuration.
| 
| make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
| make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
| make: *** No rule to make target `include/config/auto.conf', needed by `include/config/kernel.release'.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/user/setup-scripts/build/tmp-defaultsetup-eglibc-eglibc/work/nitrogen6x-oe-linux-gnueabi/linux-boundary/3.0.35-r0/temp/log.do_compile.8182)

**ERROR: Task 4 (/home/user/setup-scripts/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-boundary_3.0.35.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'**
```

I really don't know what happens. I try to restart from beginning by generating a new image with **bitbake cth-base-image** but the result is the same (which is the error above).

Comment: *Patch physical to virtual translations at runtime* says **aborted**.  You need to fix up your `.config` so that you either select YES or NO.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i suppose that by saying "i have to fix up my.config", you want to say that i have to reconfigure and build the image. I've already done that. As a matter of fact, i've completely remove my.config file and i've regenerate a new image with    bitbake cth-base-image. It's just after activating the atheros module in my kernel with make menuconfig, i cannot compile my kernel anymore so that the change i made take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, everything is fixed now. I have generate another kernel image with bitbake & openembedded. And then, i activate the rt5370 in the kernel with bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig. Here is some threads i've followed: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/UlL4e0_O_UE

Comment: I think in those instructions, there is a `cp */defconfig .config`, which is in effect doing what I suggested.